# Why can't I open my site in Designer?

Tags: permissions

So I'm trying to open my (test)site.

www.xxxxx@1981md.onmicrosoft.com in Sharepoint Designer. My account is a Global admin, and in sharepoint im the primary admin and admin of the group of webpages?

I get 403 forbidden.

Comment: For the site you're trying to open, under `Site Settings` => `Site Collection Administration` => `SharePoint Designer Settings` do you see `Enable SharePoint Designer` checked at the top? (url is `<site_base_url>/_layouts/15/SharePointDesignerSettings.aspx`)

Comment: Yes, the top-one is checked. Which is the only one checked. When trying to check the other ones(to see) I get a message about me not having permission. How Can I not have permission when the account trying with is Global?

Answer (score 1):

I think I know the issue. Connect to your tenant using:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com
```

Authenticate, and then run this:

```
Set-SPOsite https://tenantname/sites/sitename -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

I am pretty sure you need to have custom scripting enabled in order to open (and edit) the site collection.